# reading two column file line by line

Tags: python, for-loop, split

i have two column of file as arranged in the input file.I just want to read line by line and want to define the both items of each line to different variable.

For example while reading the file i need x = bht.sac0.SAC  and y = 2017-01-01T01:01:00.000000Z.....so on

input file

```
bht.sac0.SAC    2017-01-01T01:01:00.000000Z
bht.sac1.SAC    2017-01-01T02:02:00.000000Z
bht.sac2.SAC    2017-01-01T03:03:00.000000Z
bht.sac3.SAC    2017-01-01T04:04:00.000000Z
bht.sac4.SAC    2017-01-01T05:05:00.000000Z
bht.sac5.SAC    2017-01-01T06:06:00.000000Z
```

i tried the code:

```
for x,y in inputfile:
    print(x)
    print(y)
```

But it doesnot give what i expect,I hope experts may help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
with open("file.txt") as inputfile:
    for line in inputfile:
        x, y = line.split()
        print(x)
        print(y)

bht.sac0.SAC
2017-01-01T01:01:00.000000Z
bht.sac1.SAC
2017-01-01T02:02:00.000000Z
bht.sac2.SAC
2017-01-01T03:03:00.000000Z
bht.sac3.SAC
2017-01-01T04:04:00.000000Z
bht.sac4.SAC
2017-01-01T05:05:00.000000Z
bht.sac5.SAC
2017-01-01T06:06:00.000000Z
```